# How to calculate pivot value from OHLC data with multiple groupby column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, finance, technical-indicator

I've a pandas dataset with open, high, low, close, key1 and key2 column. Now I want to group the dataset by key1 and key2 and calculate pivot with the formula - (high + low + close) / 3. Upto this I'm able to do. But the requirement is to shift the calculated data to next group which I'm unable to code.

I'm able to group the dataset by key1 and key2 column and able to calculate pivot data by below code but unable to shift values on next group.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([[110, 115, 105, 111, 1, 2],[11, 16, 6, 12, 1, 2],[12, 17, 7, 13, 1, 3],[22, 25, 17, 20, 1, 3],[12, 16, 6, 11, 2, 4],[32, 36, 26, 28, 2, 4],[9, 13, 4, 13, 2, 5],[49, 53, 40, 45, 2, 5],[13, 18, 9, 12, 3, 6],[14, 16, 10, 13, 3, 6]], columns=["open","high","low","close","key1", "key2"])
s = (data.high.groupby([data.key1, data.key2]).max() + data.low.groupby([data.key1, data.key2]).min() + data.close.groupby([data.key1, data.key2]).last()) / 3
#data['pivot'] = data['key1', 'key2'].map(s.shift())
print(data)
```

When I use below code,

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([[110, 115, 105, 111, 1, 2],[11, 16, 6, 12, 1, 2],[12, 17, 7, 13, 1, 3],[22, 25, 17, 20, 1, 3],[12, 16, 6, 11, 2, 4],[32, 36, 26, 28, 2, 4],[9, 13, 4, 13, 2, 5],[49, 53, 40, 45, 2, 5],[13, 18, 9, 12, 3, 6],[14, 16, 10, 13, 3, 6]], columns=["open","high","low","close","key1", "key2"])
data['pivot'] = (data.high.groupby([data.key1, data.key2]).transform('max') + data.low.groupby([data.key1, data.key2]).transform('min') + data.close.groupby([data.key1, data.key2]).transform('last')) / 3
print(data)
```

I get below output.

```
   open  high  low  close  key1  key2      pivot
0   110   115  105    111     1     2  44.333333
1    11    16    6     12     1     2  44.333333
2    12    17    7     13     1     3  17.333333
3    22    25   17     20     1     3  17.333333
4    12    16    6     11     2     4  23.333333
5    32    36   26     28     2     4  23.333333
6     9    13    4     13     2     5  34.000000
7    49    53   40     45     2     5  34.000000
8    13    18    9     12     3     6  13.333333
9    14    16   10     13     3     6  13.333333
```

But Expected Output:

```
   open  high  low  close  key1  key2     pivot
0   110   115  105    111     1     2      NaN
1    11    16    6     12     1     2      NaN
2    12    17    7     13     1     3   44.333333
3    22    25   17     20     1     3   44.333333
4    12    16    6     11     2     4   17.333333
5    32    36   26     28     2     4   17.333333
6     9    13    4     13     2     5   23.333333
7    49    53   40     45     2     5   23.333333
8    13    18    9     12     3     6   34.000000
9    14    16   10     13     3     6   34.000000
```

Comment: Is this question [a duplicate of your earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215790/how-to-calculate-pivot-value-from-ohlc-data)? There is a lot of copy+paste here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use aggregation function with dictionary and [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and then for new column [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with `shift`:

```
s = data.groupby(['key1','key2']).agg({'low':'min','high':'max','close':'last'}).sum(axis=1)/3

data = data.join(s.rename('pivot').shift(), on=['key1','key2'])
print (data)
   open  high  low  close  key1  key2      pivot
0   110   115  105    111     1     2        NaN
1    11    16    6     12     1     2        NaN
2    12    17    7     13     1     3  44.333333
3    22    25   17     20     1     3  44.333333
4    12    16    6     11     2     4  17.333333
5    32    36   26     28     2     4  17.333333
6     9    13    4     13     2     5  23.333333
7    49    53   40     45     2     5  23.333333
8    13    18    9     12     3     6  34.000000
9    14    16   10     13     3     6  34.000000
```